# Keep Jekyll output files from permalink generation

Tags: jekyll

I have one page - `hello.html`. For this page i have two languages which are defined in a config file. Also i have two different output directories configuration, different the original file name - `en/` and `pl/`. Now, i can generate one lang by dedicated config, after this i can do this for second one.

My question is how to keep `en/` directory when i'm generating `pl/` one and reverse, how to prevent removing them form `public` output directory?

Using `keep_files` jekyll config feature is not working because output directory/file name is different then original.

Hope that this is clear enough.

Comment: Why don't you generate the directories in the same pass?

Comment: bc it generates complicated final urls

Comment: Why don't you generate the directories in the same pass with the same urls than when generated in two passes?

Comment: what? don't understand

Comment: I can't see why you need 1 config file per language. Your question looks like an XY problem for me. What is the exact content of your config files, what are the "complicated final urls" generated, and what are the final urls you expect to be generated?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind having two config files, exclude the `en` files in your `pl` config, and vice versa. For example, in your `pl` _config.yml:

```
exclude: ["en"]
```

In your `en` _config.yml:

```
exclude: ["pl"]
```

From https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/:

> **Exclude**
>
> Exclude directories and/or files from the conversion. These exclusions are relative to the site's source directory and cannot be outside the source directory.
>
> `exclude: [DIR, FILE, ...]`

Comment: i can't exclude these files because they are not exist, i have hello file which is generated to two separated languages as a `en/pl` permalinks